# How do I stop VSCode from starting so many conda instances?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

VSCode has started taking up about 60-70% of my CPU when I am developing in Python even when my code is not running. For some reason it has started opening 6 or 7 conda instances that all take 10% of my processor and I have to manually kill all but one of them. Does anyone know why this might be happening and how I can stop it?

As an example, I opened VSCode with a python notebook and this is what it looks like:

[image: VSCode Task Manager]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much of a fix but I was able to stop it from happening by downgrading the Python extension for VSCode to version v2021.12.1559732655